# Loading Wordpress posts through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So, I have this `<div>` in which my blog posts are contained. Its class is `.post`. What I want to do is that every time someone clicks on the recent posts at the widget area, the content is loaded through Ajax instead of refreshing the page.

Here is my code

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery(".umrp-list li a").click(function(){ //here I select the links of the widget
        var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        jQuery(".post").html('<div class="loading">Loading Content...</div>');
        jQuery(".post").load(post_url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

So I have two problems

1. Whenever I click on a "Recent Posts" link, the content loads where I want it to load, but my webpage is idle/frozen for about 2 seconds after the click. Why is that happening?
2. When I click for the first time, everything works except the detail I described above. When I click for the second time (another link or even the same) then instead of loading the post I clicked, it loads my whole webpage on that `.post` container. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What happens if you add a `preventDefault()` action in your click code? Change the click to: `click(function(e){` Then add `e.prventDefault();` within the function.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that at the `single.php` (it's where the blog post template is stored), I forgot to erase `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` Now everything is great!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're sending the request synchronously.  Synchronous operations are blocking, whereas asynchronous operations allow the UI to continue functioning while the operation completes behind the scenes.

As for the second issue, it sounds like jQuery(this) is somehow pointing to the document instead of the context of the element.  Check your "this" value the second time around and it'll probably provide you with some insight.

Comment: Hey there David. 

About the synchronous/asynchronous thing, I will have to check it.

As for the `this` I actually tested it by `alert(this)` whenever the click is triggered and the URL is actually the correct one but it still doesn't load it as it should.

The only weird thing that I saw is that when I click it for the first time, all the slashes `\` of the URL are alerted as slashes whilst the second time they are alerted as `%2F`

Comment: @Stevenson What is the value of jQuery(".post") the second time through in jQuery(".post").load(post_url);?

Comment: How can I check that David?

Comment: @Stevenson When you're debugging (and you should be debugging this with either firebug in firefox or developer tools in Chrome), you can watch the value of jQuery(".post") when at a breakpoint on that line.  That will allow you to tell what you're actually loading to

Comment: God ! You are not going to believe it! It had nothing to do with anything!!!

At the `single.php` (it's where the blog post template is stored), I forgot to erase `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Now everything is great!

Comment: lol, it's so funny how the littlest things can trip you up!  Glad you found it!